# Elastic Beanstalk doesn't deliver all environment variables to application

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Django app on Elastic Beanstalk. Previous version of my app had 11 environment variables  in Elastic Beanstalk and worked fine. Latest version requires two more.

I have spent several hours wondering why the app doesn't work anymore, before noticing that two environment variables do not exist in os.environ! One of the missing variables is a new variable added today, and the other one worked earlier. Second new variable can be found in os.environ.

Length of the variables don't come close to the maximum of 4 KB.

How is this possible?

EDIT: I deleted one of the new variables, and now all 12 environment variables work?!